# How to register payment using Python XML-RPC in Odoo 12

Tags: python, api, odoo, payment, xml-rpc

First I created the function:

```
def invoiceRegisterPayment(self,register_payment_row):        
    confirm_result = self.ODOO_OBJECT.execute_kw(
        self.DATA, 
        self.UID, 
        self.PASS, 
        'account.payment', 
        'action_validate_invoice_payment', 
        register_payment_row)        
    return confirm_result
```

Then I passed the following parameters:

```
register_payment_row = [
    [payment_id],
    {
        "active_id":invoice_id,
        "active_ids":[invoice_id],
        "active_model": "account.invoice",
        "default_invoice_ids":[[4,invoice_id,None]],
        "journal_type":"sale",
        "lang":"en_US",
        "search_disable_custom_filters": True,
        "type": "out_invoice",
        "tz": False,
        "uid": 2
    } ]
```

But it shows the following error: "This method should only be called to process a single invoice's payment."

This is the print of register_payment_row:

```
[[67], {'active_id': 119, 'active_ids': [119], 'active_model': 'account.invoice', 'default_invoice_ids': [4, 119, None], 'journal_type': 'sale', 'lang': 'en_US', 'search_disable_custom_filters': True, 'type': 'out_invoice', 'tz': False, 'uid': 2}]
```

Comment: Try to pass `register_payment_row` as a dictionary by extracting `[payment_id],` from it, and instead add `[payment_id],` to `self.ODOO_OBJECT.execute_kw()` right before `register_payment_row`

Comment: Still gives me the same error

def invoiceRegisterPayment(self,payment_id,register_payment_row):
confirm_result = self.ODOO_OBJECT.execute_kw(self.DATA, self.UID, self.PASS, 'account.payment', 'action_validate_invoice_payment', [payment_id,register_payment_row])
return confirm_result

Comment: I have the same problem as I also followed how the suggested data structure to be passed in the action_validate_invoice_payment method.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following data structure and pass to create method **account.payment** model.

```
 { invoice_ids: [ [ 4, "Invoice Id", 'None' ] ],
  default_invoice_ids: [ [ 4, "Invoice Id", 'None' ] ],
  amount: 'Amount',
  payment_date: '2019-05-21 02:55:52',
  payment_type: 'inbound',
  has_invoices: true,
  currency_id: 1,
  journal_id: 6,
  payment_method_id: 1,
  partner_id: 226,
  partner_type: 'customer',
  communication: 'INV/2019/0141/44',
  name: 'INV/2019/0141/44' }
```