# How to register a payment to an invoice in Odoo 11 via XML RPC

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I'm using the Odoo External API (in python: odoorpc) to facilitate communication between a customer app (used to place orders) and my Odoo Online instance. I'm currently not able to register a payment using XML RPC.

I have successfully created sales orders and I can create and validate invoices for them. The last step is to register a payment (which are handled completely outside of Odoo, so I just have to register them for accounting purposes), but I can't get it to work.

## create invoice

```py
x = odoo.execute_kw('sale.order', 'action_invoice_create', [[sales_order]], {'context': {'active_ids': sales_order}})[0]
```

## validate invoice

```py
odoo.execute_kw('account.invoice', 'action_invoice_open', [[x]], {})
```

## register payment (i found this code in another topic)

```py
mod = odoo.env['account.payment']
id = mod.create({'amount': 32, 'payment_date': '2018-12-25 00:00:01', 'payment_type': 'inbound', 'payment_method_id': 2, 'journal_id': 8, 'currency_id': 1, 'partner_id': 853} )
mod.browse(id).invoice_ids = [x]
mod.browse(id).post()
```

## register payment second attempt:

```py
odoo.execute_kw('account.payment', 'action_validate_invoice_payment', [[288],{
        "active_id":x,
        "active_ids":[x],
        "active_model": "account.invoice",
        "default_invoice_ids":[x],
        "journal_type":"sale",
        "search_disable_custom_filters": True,
        "type": "out_invoice",
        "tz": False
    }])
```

I'm getting this error on both attempts to register my payment.

RPCError: local variable 'sequence_code' referenced before assignment

Comment: Please refer to my answer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56231368/5275065

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error states, that a variable isn't set properly: The code can be found [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/fe8e462822de85d7f817fed09ac6e3b5521072ab/addons/account/models/account_payment.py#L498-L511)

```py
        if rec.payment_type == 'transfer':
            sequence_code = 'account.payment.transfer'
        else:
            if rec.partner_type == 'customer':
                if rec.payment_type == 'inbound':
                    sequence_code = 'account.payment.customer.invoice'
                if rec.payment_type == 'outbound':
                    sequence_code = 'account.payment.customer.refund'
            if rec.partner_type == 'supplier':
                if rec.payment_type == 'inbound':
                    sequence_code = 'account.payment.supplier.refund'
                if rec.payment_type == 'outbound':
                    sequence_code = 'account.payment.supplier.invoice'
        rec.name = self.env['ir.sequence'].with_context(ir_sequence_date=rec.payment_date).next_by_code(sequence_code)
```

`rec` is the payment you've created with `mod.create()` and the error belongs to the call of `post()`.
You've forgotten to set a `partner_type` for the payment, which should be `customer` in your case.

Maybe there will be more errors, but your specific problem should be solved by setting `partner_type`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm now one step closer. However, if I try to register the payment using the second method, I'll get the following error: 'This method should only be called to process a single invoice\'s payment.' I only entered one invoice and one payment id. Any hints for this one?

Comment: Also having the issue of his method should only be called to process a single invoice\'s payment everytime I validate invoice payment.